# ios13 notification content custom height

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, ios13, rich-notifications

Our code was working with previous versions, but on iOS13 the custom notification content height is not working properly. Everything is visible as it should be, but the buttons are not clickable after a part of view. So for example after 320 pixel the custom views are not clickable. Running the same code on ios12 works.

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {

   let content = notification.request.content
            
   self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: contentH)
   self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
   self.view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Any solution? Or is it an iOS13 bug?

##Update :

We are developing our app on iOS14 beta and the issue is still here. Just one thing is new related to this. When we are tapping the screen this is what we get.

> NotificationContent[44466:2340668] [Assert]
> UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer was moved to a view
> that isn't a scroll view, so we can't determine if the touch is on a
> scroll indicator.

We are adding all the subviews to the viewcontroller's view (no custom containers).

Comment: I think it is a bug in my case nothing is visible when it is iOS 13.0 I guess but working fine on all other OS

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where you are setting the heights and widths from but alot has changed following IOS 13 for Notifications and Push notifications both , While push notifications remain a big hassel having to change tockens and more biggest effect for notifications is many of the UIApplicationDelegate lifecycle methods are no longer called.

There are now corresponding lifecycle methods in the UISceneDelegate. This means there is a need to listen to the UIScene.didEnterBackgroundNotification notification under iOS 13. Now that you may think that it does not have a direct effect on a height or a width of a notification , i faced something of that sort and having moving someone them accroding to the New lifecylce methods they rendered properly .

Im Not sure if your issue will be sorted but also take alook at the below link. Might help you.Even i refered to this while i was facing the issues

[View controller responds to app delegate notifications in iOS 12 but not in iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57488057/view-controller-responds-to-app-delegate-notifications-in-ios-12-but-not-in-ios)

Comment: No the problem is not related to these things, I ve already reported this bug to apple, hopefully somebody will answer it or fix